# how to get the json values on multiple json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ecmascript-6

In the below code i want to get the value of the women i,e i'm getting 1.Personal care appliances and 2. Jewelry... but after that if i check any checkbox then i'm getting error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" and also if i select multiple checkboxes then i should get the values of all checkboxes.

**allcat.json**

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":"47",
      "name":"Women",
      "parent":"0",
      "status":"Enabled",
      "itemcount":44,
      "siblings":[ 
         { 
            "id":"87",
            "name":"Personal Care Appliances",
            "parent":"47",
            "status":"Enabled",
            "itemcount":2,
            "siblings":[ 
               { 
                  "id":"88",
                  "name":"Hair Dryers",
                  "parent":"87",
                  "status":"Enabled",
                  "itemcount":2,
                  "siblings":[ 

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "id":"127",
            "name":"Jewellary",
            "parent":"47",
            "status":"Enabled",
            "itemcount":41,
            "siblings":[ 
               { 
                  "id":"128",
                  "name":"Artificial Jewellary",
                  "parent":"127",
                  "status":"Enabled",
                  "itemcount":41,
                  "siblings":[ 

                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**html**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group form-inline text-center">
    <label for="select_category">Select Category</label>&emsp;
    <select class="custom-select" id="select_category" style="width: 500px;" onchange="listcatcb();">
        <option selected></option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="container" id="cats">
    <div class="form-check" id="catrbs"> </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="nextcats();">Click Next!</button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="selected-item"></div>
```

**javascript**

```js
function getallcategory() {
    $.getJSON("allcat.json", function (json) {
        var link = json;
        for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
            $("#select_category").append('<option value="' + link[i].name + '">' + link[i].name + '</option> ')
        }
    })
}

function listcatcb() {
    selcat = document.getElementById("select_category").value;
    $.getJSON("allcat.json", function (json) {
        var obj = json;
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].name == selcat) {
                for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].siblings.length; j++) {
                    $("#catrbs").append('<input class="form-check-input catcbs" type="checkbox" id="' + obj[i].siblings[
                        j].name + '" value="' + obj[i].siblings[j].name + '"><label class="form-check-label" for="' +
                        obj[i].siblings[j].name + '">' +
                        obj[i].siblings[j].name +
                        '</label><br/>')
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

function nextcats() {
    $.getJSON("allcat.json", function (json) {
        console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
        var obj = json;
        console.log(obj);
        var checkedValue = $('.catcbs:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        var selectedItem = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].name == selcat) {
                for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].siblings.length; j++) {
                    if (checkedValue.indexOf(obj[i].siblings[j].name) != -1) {
                        for (var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
                            selectedItem += `<p>${obj[i].siblings[j].siblings[k].name}</p>`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $('#selected-item').html(selectedItem)
    });
}
getallcategory();
```

Comment: Hi, I run your code in my local but I didn't get any error as you mentioned above. it's working fine.
try to use `['name']` instead of `.name` maybe it will help.

Comment: Hai manoj, your console says CORS error, due to chrome security reasons, we are not supposed to get data from local files. you need to export your data from a js file and add to your html file. e.g. put your json data as `var jsonData = [...]` in a `.js` file and add that `.js` file to your html file, like adding `external js` files. then you can access those variables in other js file, like in your `script.js` file, you can get the `json data` by calling the variable `jsonData`.

Comment: etta.... i tried that also but same error im getting again.. i gave script src and saved my json array as .js extension

Answer (score 0):

In the `nextcats()` function, you're looping on `obj`, then `obj[i].siblings` and then `obj` again. You probably meant to loop on `obj[i].siblings[j].siblings` :

```js
// loop on obj
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].name == selcat) {

        // loop on obj[i].siblings
        for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].siblings.length; j++) {
            if (checkedValue.indexOf(obj[i].siblings[j].name) != -1) {

                // loop on obj[i].siblings[j].siblings
                for (var k = 0; k < obj[i].siblings[j].length; k++) {
                    selectedItem += `<p>${obj[i].siblings[j].siblings[k].name}</p>`;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you still get the error? Does it says on which line it happens?

Comment: no sir im not getting any error as well as im not getting output also

Comment: Is the JSON loading correctly? If you add ```console.log(json)``` as first statement of the ```getJSON``` callback, you get the correct content?

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the same and didn't find any issue. The only change I have made is to have the json file as a constant variable instead of loading it through a file.

```js
const json = [{
  "id": "47",
  "name": "Women",
  "parent": "0",
  "status": "Enabled",
  "itemcount": 44,
  "siblings": [{
      "id": "87",
      "name": "Personal Care Appliances",
      "parent": "47",
      "status": "Enabled",
      "itemcount": 2,
      "siblings": [{
        "id": "88",
        "name": "Hair Dryers",
        "parent": "87",
        "status": "Enabled",
        "itemcount": 2,
        "siblings": [

        ]
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": "127",
      "name": "Jewellary",
      "parent": "47",
      "status": "Enabled",
      "itemcount": 41,
      "siblings": [{
        "id": "128",
        "name": "Artificial Jewellary",
        "parent": "127",
        "status": "Enabled",
        "itemcount": 41,
        "siblings": [

        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
}]

function getallcategory() {
        var link = json;
        for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
            $("#select_category").append('<option value="' + link[i].name + '">' + link[i].name + '</option> ')
        }
}

function listcatcb() {
    selcat = document.getElementById("select_category").value;
        var obj = json;
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].name == selcat) {
                for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].siblings.length; j++) {
                    $("#catrbs").append('<input class="form-check-input catcbs" type="checkbox" id="' + obj[i].siblings[
                        j].name + '" value="' + obj[i].siblings[j].name + '"><label class="form-check-label" for="' +
                        obj[i].siblings[j].name + '">' +
                        obj[i].siblings[j].name +
                        '</label><br/>')
                }
            }
        }
}

function nextcats() {
        var obj = json;
        var checkedValue = $('.catcbs:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        var selectedItem = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].name == selcat) {
                for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].siblings.length; j++) {
                    if (checkedValue.indexOf(obj[i].siblings[j].name) != -1) {
                        for (var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
                            selectedItem += `<p>${obj[i].siblings[j].siblings[k].name}</p>`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $('#selected-item').html(selectedItem)
}
getallcategory();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group form-inline text-center">
    <label for="select_category">Select Category</label>&emsp;
    <select class="custom-select" id="select_category" style="width: 500px;" onchange="listcatcb();">
        <option selected></option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="container" id="cats">
    <div class="form-check" id="catrbs"> </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="nextcats();">Click Next!</button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="selected-item"></div>
```

Comment: sir, but that json array file is not variable i'm retrieving from allcat.json

Comment: you don't need to load to the file like that. You could simply use ES6's import statement and assign the file to a variable. What I showed you is just an example.

`import JSON from './<your-file-path>`